# "Failed opening required" при попытке установить virtuemart

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

При попытке установить virtuemart на сайт на джумле 1.5 бъет следующую ошибку:

> Warning:
>   require(/home/v/valensia/public_html/shop/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/helpers/config.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in /home/v/valensia/public_html/shop/vmshop/script.vmallinone.php on
>   line 325

```
Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/v/valensia/public_html/shop/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/helpers/config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/v/valensia/public_html/shop/vmshop/script.vmallinone.php on line 325
```

Чем это может быть вызвано?
Установку произвожу через Загрузку файла пакета.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не настроены права доступа.

Comment: Исправил старую ошибку, но появилась новая =( Не подскажите в чем дело?

Comment: А что у вас на 325 строчке файла script.vmallinone.php?